# JSTileMap(.tmx) vs Xcode SKTileMapNode

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, xcode8, jstilemap

Can someone tell us which one is the better choice and list some pro/cons?

**For games** -> .tmx?

**for other reasons** -> SKTileMapNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the [JSTileMap](https://github.com/slycrel/JSTileMap) ReadMe page on GitHub it recommends to use SKTilemapNode. This is a clear indication of a direction to follow.

JSTileMap is written in Objective-C and seems like no intention to port to Swift exists, that would be enough of a reason to choose SKTilemapNode.